# How to a list of arns for the aws resources that are using the iam certificate using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

How can I list AWS resources that are using an IAM certificate using boto3.
I am trying to exact something similar to "InUseBy" of parameter we have in [describe_certificate](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/acm.html#ACM.Client.describe_certificate) of ACM certs

Can someone please help me here?

I tried get get_available_subresources() of IAM boto3 but it did not solve my purpose

```
    client = boto3.client( 'iam', region_name="us-west-2" )
    iam_resource = boto3.resource( 'iam' )
    response = client.list_server_certificates()
    certificateList = response['ServerCertificateMetadataList']

    for certificate in certificateList:
        server_certificate = iam_resource.ServerCertificate( str(repr( certificate["ServerCertificateName"] )) )
        resources = server_certificate.get_available_subresources()
```

Comment: "it did not solve my purpose" - clould you provide more details? Why it does not work for you? Any errors, timeouts?

Comment: @marcin It does not give me list of resources that are using that IAM certificate